# count within foreach doesn't work in my case

Tags: php

```
foreach ($dom->find('.post h1 a') as $checkIfResultTrue2) {
    $totalSearchResult = $checkIfResultTrue2->href;

        if(count($totalSearchResult) > 1){
            echo "more than 1";
        }
     }
```

why this didn't print more than 1? I tried .length but realised that is JS. I tried sizeof and count, no luck. When I echo $totalSearchResult, there are more than 1 links there.. hmm, what is the problem?

Comment: Can you post a var_dump($checkIfResultTrue2) ?

Comment: @Daan marian0 example work.. but any thought to get the first item in foreach loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you overwrite value of `$totalSearchResult` as string. If `$totalSearchResult` is an array, you should write to it as follow:

```
$totalSearchResult = array();
foreach ($dom->find('.post h1 a') as $checkIfResultTrue2) {
    $totalSearchResult[] = $checkIfResultTrue2->href;
    ...
}
```

Comment: cool, it work. Have any thought of getting the first totalSearchResult?

Comment: You mean to get value of first element of this array like `$totalSearchResult[0]`?

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting one variable. Take that variable as array, and add every elements in that array. It should be,

```
$totalSearchResult=array();

foreach ($dom->find('.post h1 a') as $checkIfResultTrue2) {
array_push($totalSearchResult, $checkIfResultTrue2->href);        <---

    if(count($totalSearchResult) > 1){
        echo "more than 1";
    }
 }
```